# How to refresh the software sources in Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center

I have added a PPA repository to my fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04 with the **Software sources** menu item in the **Ubuntu Software Center** (USC). The problem is that **the new repository is not immediately available**. I can't find an option to refresh the software sources in the USC. I have tried to close the USC and reopen it, but no success.
I don't know if this is a question of time (USC needs some time to refresh?), or if I'm doing something wrong.
In the meantime I had to install another software, so I have installed this one. At the end of the installation I have checked out again the software sources, and this time the new PPA repository was there. So, there is some kind of software sources refresh, but I don't know how to force it.

There is somebody else that had this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The software sources needs to be updated. You can do this a couple of ways:
Running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Starting Update Manager and clicking "Check".
The software sources cannot be updated within USC.

Comment: While that works, it seems like adding a new software source should trigger an update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command-line to update the software repositories.

```
$ sudo apt update
```